# Bootstrap 3 .container-fluid with a 50-50 split

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here's my challenge. The design calls for a full width row with a 50-50 split. Each half is a different colour. Ok, easy enough. Other rows will be the fixed .container width with 12 columns

In each half, on desktop, the content would conform to a fixed container width, each width 6 columns, on large, then 12 on mobile.

I've attached a slice from the PSD.

[image: full width, two columns]

Here's my initial code as i work through this.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <div class="container-fluid dualColour">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 c1" style="background:red;">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p>Copy example</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 c2" style="background:green">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
              <p>Copy example</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm unsure how to have the content sit within the 1170 container width, without a lot of custom CSS and html.

Comment: May be use have not loaded bootstrap.css or it is missing from the location

Comment: Answered in another question: <https://stackoverflow.com/a/28870986/1437615>

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="navy">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Header 1</h2>
        <p>Copy example</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <div class="light">
      <div class="content">
        <h2>Header 2</h2>
        <p>Copy example</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm leaning towards this type of thing, and then fixing the width of .content based on breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that without so much code. Is dealing more with structure. Mantaining responsivity and using bootstrap 4 classes:

HTML

```
<div class="position-relative">
  <div class="container-fluid background-holder">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-md-6 bg-primary">
        <p class="text-left">left split</p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 bg-warning">
        <p class="text-right">right split</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <section class="col-md-6">
        <h1>left content</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eget mauris ut enim scelerisque sollicitudin in nec nisl. Quisque arcu arcu, bibendum id nunc sit amet, auctor bibendum tellus. Sed non scelerisque nulla. Sed pharetra lacus sapien, et condimentum
        ante condimentum non. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Fusce magna lorem, lacinia congue varius blandit, facilisis quis nulla. Maecenas eu finibus tortor, sed volutpat justo. Fusce pulvinar
      </section>
      <section class="col-md-6">
        <h1>right content</h1>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque eget mauris ut enim scelerisque sollicitudin in nec nisl. Quisque arcu arcu, bibendum id nunc sit amet, auctor bibendum tellus. diam at placerat consectetur. Aliquam nec nisl luctus, imperdiet
        dolor non, feugiat ligula.
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.background-holder {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container {
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}
```

[jsfiddle DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sparhawk_odin/47w18h6o/)